# Adding tuples of lists to a list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I don't understand the syntax of adding tuples whose elements are also elements of a list to another list that encompasses all of the information.

I'm trying to create a trajectory list that contains tuples of flight data of a projectile during flight. I want to use tuples so that I can see all of the information for each moment in time.

```
import random
import math

gg = -9.81 # gravity m/s**2
tt = 10 **-9 # seconds
wind = random.randint(-10,10)   # m/s

#position
x=random.randint(0,100)   # m/s

#projectile

v0 = float(raw_input('Enter the initial velocity (m/s) -> '));
theta = float(raw_input('Enter the initial launch angle of projectile (degrees) -> '));

theta *= (180/3.14159265359)

xx = [x]
yy = [.000000000000000000001]
dz =[v0]
time = [0];


data = ( time, xx, yy, dz)
traj = [data]


while yy[-1] >0:

    traj.append ( math.sqrt( (traj[-1][3][-1] * math.sin(theta) + gg * tt)** 2+        (traj[-1][4] * math.cos(theta) -wind) ** 2 ))    # velocity
    traj.append ( traj[-1][2][-1] + dz[-1] * math.sin(theta) * tt + .5* gg * tt)    # y position
    traj.append ( traj[-1][1][-1] * dz[-1] * math.cos(theta) - wind * tt)    # x position
    traj.append ( traj[-1][0][-1] + tt)     # time


print traj
```

Edit:
I would input integers for the initial angle and velocity (i.e.-45,45). Expected outputs would be a list of tuples containing four elements corresponding to the time, x coordinate, y coordinate, and velocity, respectively. Currently, I'm receiving a tuple index out of range error.

Comment: It will be helpful if you show: 1. sample input 2. expected output 3. actual output

Comment: Welcome to S.O.! You should tell us what your inputs and outputs are, and how your outputs differ from your expectation. http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: you have multiple problems in your while loop, you need to print out traj in the loop to see where you are going wrong

Comment: Apart from the other problems here, `theta *= (180/3.14159265359)` is wrong, since it converts radians to degrees; you want `theta *= 3.14159265359/180`, or even better, `theta = math.radians(theta)`.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have

```
traj[-1][4]
```

in your first `traj.append` line, `traj[-1]` is `data`, and `data` is only four elements long, so the last item is at index 3.

Comment: I diagnosed the first error I saw, @Padraic. Feel free to rewrite the whole program for him/her and put everything right.

Comment: there are so many errors, I would have to rewrite 90 percent of the code, the OP will learn more doing their own debugging.

Comment: There is a chance I was being sarcastic.

Comment: since you have the energy to be sarcastic and since you already starting answering the question you may as well rewrite all the code yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you append data the values you compute in the while loop to the `traj` list. This will not update the lists `xx`, `yy`, `time` or `dz`.
You could modify the code in the following way

```
while yy[-1] > 0:
    dz_next = math.sqrt( (yy[-1] * math.sin(theta) + gg * tt)** 2+(dz[-1] * math.cos(theta) -wind)** 2)
    yy_next = yy[-1] + dz[-1] * math.sin(theta) * tt + .5* gg * tt
    xx_next = xx[-1] * dz[-1] * math.cos(theta) - wind * tt

    dz.append(dz_next)    # velocity
    yy.append(yy_next)    # y position
    xx.append(xx_next)    # x position
    time.append(time[-1] + tt)     # time
```

I think a better way would be the following

```
data = ( 0, x, 1e-20, v0) # initial data
traj = [data]

while True:
    t, x, y, v = traj[-1]
    if y < 0:
        break

    traj.append((t + tt, # time
                 x * v * math.cos(theta) - wind * tt, # x position
                 y + v * math.sin(theta) * tt + .5* gg * tt, # y position
                 (y* math.sin(theta) + gg * tt)** 2 + (v*math.cos(theta) -wind) ** 2) # velocity
    )


    print traj
    t_traj, x_traj, y_traj, z_traj = zip(*traj)
```